Не работает функция в Python на Pyside6
Подскажите, почему не работает функция "Зимний"? def funcWinter(self):
app.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from design import Ui_root

sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #new prop\norm
        self.propCity = None
        self.propHighway = None
        self.normCity = None
        self.normHighway = None
        self.propCityWinter = None
        self.normCityWinter = None
        self.propHighwayWinter = None
        self.normHighwayWinter = None
        #function
        self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
        self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)
        #menubar
        self.btnAbout.clicked.connect(self.funcAbout)
        self.btnHelp.clicked.connect(self.funcHelp)
        self.btnGear.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnGear.clicked.connect(self.funcGear)
        #summer
        self.applyPropCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropCitySummer)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormCitySummer)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwaySummer)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwaySummer)
        #winter
        self.applyPropCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropCityWinter)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormCityWinter)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwayWinter)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwayWinter)

    # summer
    def funcSummer(self):
        try:
            # Пропорции город лето
            if self.propCity:
                propCity = self.propCity
            else:
                propCity = 0.3
            # Нормы город лето
            if self.normCity:
                normCity = self.normCity
            else:
                normCity = 11.5
            # Пропорции трасса лето
            if self.propHighway:
                propHighway = self.propHighway
            else:
                propHighway = 0.7
            # Нормы трасса лето
            if self.normHighway:
                normHighway = self.normHighway
            else:
                normHighway = 8.5

            inSummer = float(self.inputSummer.text())
            roadCity = round(propCity * inSummer, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
            totalSummer = round((propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity) + (propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway),
                                2)
            totalCity = round(inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            totalHighway = round(inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)

            self.outSummer.setText(
                f' '
                f'Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш общий расход {totalSummer} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Город 100% {totalCity} литров\n'
                f' Трасса 100% {totalHighway} литров'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propCity = float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropCitySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newNormCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normCity = float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormCitySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newPropHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propHighway = float(self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text()}</b>")

    def newNormHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normHighway = float(self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так. <br>"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные. <br><b>{self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text()}</b>")

    # winter
    def funcWinter(self):

        try:
            if self.propCityWinter:                     # Пропорции город зима
                propCityWinter = self.propCityWinter
            else:
                propCityWinter = 0.3

            if self.normCityWinter:                     # Нормы город зима
                normCityWinter = self.normCityWinter
            else:
                normCityWinter = 13.8

            if self.propHighwayWinter:                  # Пропорции трасса зима
                propHighwayWinter = self.propHighwayWinter
            else:
                propHighwayWinter = 0.7

            if self.normHighwayWinter:                  # Нормы трасса зима
                normHighwayWinter = self.normHighwayWinter
            else:
                normHighwayWinter = 10.2

            inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
            roadCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter, 2)
            totalWinter = round((propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter) + (
                    propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter),
                                2)

            self.outWinter.setText(
                f' '
                f'Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш общий расход {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Город 100% {totalCity} литров\n'
                f' Трасса 100% {totalHighway} литров'
            )

        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propCityWinter = float(self.inputPropCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normCityWinter = float(self.inputNormCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propHighwayWinter = float(self.inputPropHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normHighwayWinter = float(self.inputNormHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    # about
    def funcGear(self):
        if self.btnGear.isChecked():
            self.resize(560, 670)
        else:
            self.resize(560, 450)

    @staticmethod
    def funcAbout():
        strAbout = """
            BenzConfig ver. 1.0\n
            Copyright © Чекаев В.А.
            Ресурсы www.flaticon.com\n
            Лицензия
            GNU General Public License v3.0
            """

        msgAbout = QMessageBox()
        msgAbout.setWindowTitle("About")
        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('infoMenu.svg'))
        msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
        msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("iconAbout.png"))
        msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgAbout.exec()

    @staticmethod
    def funcHelp():
        strAbout = """
        Первичные пропорции перерасчета расхода город/трасса 30% на 70%\n
        Новые параметры пропорций вносить в формате от 0.1 до 0.9
        чтобы сумма летнего и зимнего составляла 1.0\n
        Параметры норм расхода вносить через точку 
        Пример: 10.5\n
        HOTKEYS
        Рассчет Летнего расхода клавиша "Enter"
        Рассчет Зимнего расхода клавиша "Tab"
        """

        msgAbout = QMessageBox()
        msgAbout.setWindowTitle("Help")
        msgAbout.setWindowIcon(QIcon('helpMenu.svg'))
        msgAbout.setText(strAbout)
        #msgAbout.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("IconHelp.png"))
        msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgAbout.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

design.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
                            QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
                            QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
                           QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
                           QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
                           QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow,
                               QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QTabWidget, QWidget)
import files_rc


class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")
        root.resize(560, 450)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 450))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 670))
        root.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        root.setMouseTracking(False)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        root.setWindowIcon(icon)
        root.setWindowOpacity(1.000000000000000)
        root.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        root.setStyleSheet(u"")
        root.setDocumentMode(False)
        root.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.grid_w = QWidget(root)
        self.grid_w.setObjectName(u"grid_w")
        self.grid_w.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputSummer.setObjectName(u"inputSummer")
        self.inputSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputSummer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.inputSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.inputSummer.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.inputSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.inputSummer.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.outSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outSummer.setObjectName(u"outSummer")
        self.outSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outSummer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 230);")
        self.outSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btnSummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSummer.setObjectName(u"btnSummer")
        self.btnSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnSummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.btnWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnWinter.setObjectName(u"btnWinter")
        self.btnWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.outWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outWinter.setObjectName(u"outWinter")
        self.outWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outWinter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.outWinter.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.outWinter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.inputWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputWinter.setObjectName(u"inputWinter")
        self.inputWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputWinter.setMaxLength(10)
        self.label_s = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.label_s.setObjectName(u"label_s")
        self.label_s.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 241, 21))
        self.label_s.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.lable_w = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.lable_w.setObjectName(u"lable_w")
        self.lable_w.setGeometry(QRect(300, 10, 241, 21))
        self.lable_w.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnAbout = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnAbout.setObjectName(u"btnAbout")
        self.btnAbout.setGeometry(QRect(20, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnAbout.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnAbout.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon1 = QIcon()
        icon1.addFile(u"info.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnAbout.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btnHelp = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnHelp.setObjectName(u"btnHelp")
        self.btnHelp.setGeometry(QRect(53, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnHelp.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnHelp.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon2 = QIcon()
        icon2.addFile(u"help.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnHelp.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btnHelp.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnHelp.setFlat(False)
        self.btnGear = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnGear.setObjectName(u"btnGear")
        self.btnGear.setGeometry(QRect(510, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnGear.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnGear.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon3 = QIcon()
        icon3.addFile(u"gear.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.btnGear.setIcon(icon3)
        self.labelPropSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropSummer.setObjectName(u"labelPropSummer")
        self.labelPropSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 470, 71, 16))
        self.applyPropCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropCitySummer")
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelNormSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormSummer.setObjectName(u"labelNormSummer")
        self.labelNormSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 570, 91, 16))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwaySummer")
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwaySummer")
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormCitySummer")
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        """self.defis = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.defis.setObjectName(u"defis")
        self.defis.setGeometry(QRect(20, 440, 521, 20))
        self.defis.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 200);")"""
        self.applyNormCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormCityWinter")
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwayWinter")
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropCityWinter")
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwayWinter")
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelPropWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropWinter.setObjectName(u"labelPropWinter")
        self.labelPropWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 470, 71, 16))
        self.labelNormWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormWinter.setObjectName(u"labelNormWinter")
        self.labelNormWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 570, 91, 16))
        self.inputPropCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropCitySummer")
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 491, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwaySummer")
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropCityWinter")
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 490, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwayWInter")
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormCitySummer")
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwaySummer")
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 630, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormCityWinter")
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwayWInter")
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 630, 151, 31))
        root.setCentralWidget(self.grid_w)
        self.retranslateUi(root)
        self.btnHelp.setDefault(False)
        self.btnGear.setDefault(False)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, root):
        root.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"BenzConfig", None))
        self.inputSummer.setInputMask("")
        self.inputSummer.setText("")
        self.inputSummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                       u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435",
                                                                       None))
        self.outSummer.setText("")
        self.btnSummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        #if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnSummer.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Return", None))
        #endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        #if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Tab", None))
        #endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.outWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                       u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435",
                                                                       None))
        self.label_s.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.lable_w.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.btnAbout.setText("")
        self.btnHelp.setText("")
        self.btnGear.setText("")
        self.labelPropSummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelNormSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430",
                                                                None))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        """self.defis.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                      u"__________________________________________________________________________________________________________",
                                                      None))"""
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelPropWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.labelNormWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430",
                                                                None))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwayWInter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwayWInter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
    # retranslateUi



Метод funcWinter(self) не работает потому что:

объекты totalCity и totalHighway не определены вообще;

объекты normCity и normHighway надо заменить на normCityWinter и normHighwayWinter соответственно.



...

# winter
    def funcWinter(self):
        try:
            if self.propCityWinter:                     # Пропорции город зима
                propCityWinter = self.propCityWinter
            else:
                propCityWinter = 0.3

            if self.normCityWinter:                     # Нормы город зима
                normCityWinter = self.normCityWinter
            else:
                normCityWinter = 13.8
            
            if self.propHighwayWinter:                  # Пропорции трасса зима
                propHighwayWinter = self.propHighwayWinter
            else:
                propHighwayWinter = 0.7
            
            if self.normHighwayWinter:                  # Нормы трасса зима
                normHighwayWinter = self.normHighwayWinter
            else:
                normHighwayWinter = 10.2
            
            inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
            roadCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter, 2)
            totalWinter = round((propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter) + (
                    propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter),
                                2)
# +++ добавил по аналогии как в методе funcSummer(self)
            totalCity = round(inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter, 2)
            totalHighway = round(inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter, 2)                                

            self.outWinter.setText(
                f' '
                f'Ваш пробег по городу {roadCity} км\n Потрачено по городу {resultCity} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км\n Потрачено по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Ваш общий расход {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
# !!! +++
#                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
# ----------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvv <----------------------------------
                f' Город {normCityWinter} на 100 км\n'             # !!! +++
#                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'            
# -----------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------    
                f' Трасса {normHighwayWinter} на 100 км\n\n'       # !!! +++
                
                f' Город 100% {totalCity} литров\n'
                f' Трасса 100% {totalHighway} литров'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")
...




@ S.Nick Спасибо, пол вечера мучался, не смог найти эту проблему

@ S.Nick А еще хотел спросить у вас, если в  питоне какая-нибудь библиотека или функция, чтобы вот новые внесенные параметры (пропорции и нормы) сохранялись и не сбрасывались при закрытии программы?

@VadimChekaev пожалуйста.  Если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому, то не забудьте пометить их и как полезные,  если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsettings.html и смотрим вопросы  и ответы с QSettings Class
